# iOS Development: After updating my iPhone 4 to iOS 4.3 Beta 3, my app says "This game is not recognized by Game Center"

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, game-center, ios4

I've been building an iPhone game for the last couple months using XCode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 and I'm about to submit it to the App Store.  Before I do that, however, I wanted to test it against iOS 4.3 Beta 3, so I downloaded the latest beta SDK, installed it in a separate location, and updated the device to iOS 4.3 Beta 3.  Now, when I run the game and it attempts to authenticate the local player in Game Center, it pops up a box saying "This game is not recognized by Game Center".  Why?

I tried logging out of Game Center though the Game Center app and restarting my app, but I was already logged out, so the problem doesn't appear to be the result of trying to use a non-sandboxed account. Also, I noticed that it runs fine in the 4.3 Beta 3 Simulator.  I only get this error on the updated device.  Any ideas?

Thanks so much for you wisdom!

Comment: Maybe it's because you're not supposed to submit 4.3 apps to the store? I don't know, just a thought.

Comment: @crimson_penguin yes he can't submit it to the store, but should be able to test the app in the sandbox environment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you code signing with the provisioning profile specific to your app or with a wildcard provisioning profile?
As far as I know, signing with a wildcard profile isn't allowed for accessing Game Center.

In the Game Center app, make sure you're not connected with an account in the production environment. If you have doubt, log out and start your application.

Comment: Thanks, Jilouc.  I'm using the same, non-wildcard profile that I was using when running 4.2.  Also, this error message shows when I'm logged out of Game Center completely.  Obviously I can't login to my sandbox Game Center account through the Game Center app directly, so it doesn't really leave me with much else to try.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Strange, as I was typing that last comment I just wrote, the standard in-app Game Center Login dialog box appeared and i was able to login fine.  I hate it when Apple technology just starts to magically work with no understanding of why it was broken to begin with.

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe Sorry, I'm running out of idea... I've encountered several issues with GC login but each time, logging out and "force quit" of the GC app did the trick. I wish Apple would provide more precise errors (at least in sandbox env)...  *edit* Yeah, hate it too when some kind of magic shows up and fix the mess...