# Game Center not recognized on all devices

Tags: ios, game-center

I have Game Center running perfectly on one device. However, I have the same build deployed to 3 other devices and Game Center will not work on them. The message "This game is not recognized by Game Center" is displayed.

I've read other answers and have tried suggestions such as:

- Deleting the app, signing out of game center, and doing a clean build and run
- Checking the provisioning profiles
- Verifying that the devices are not jailbroken
- Verifying that valid iTunes Connect Test User accounts are being used

Game Center was working on one of the 3 devices earlier (previously untested on the remaining 2), but has suddenly stopped working. It currently runs correctly on only 1 out of 4 devices. What could be a possible solution to this problem? Could it be a server-side problem with the Game Center sandbox?

Edit:

The devices are as follow:

- iPad 4th Gen (iOS 6.1.3) (Working)
- iPhone 4th Gen (iOS 6.1.3) (Used to work, not working now)
- iPod Touch 5th Gen (iOS 6.1.3) (Not working; newly tested)
- iPad 1st Gen (iOS 5.1.1) (Not working; newly tested)

Testing Game Center is getting very time consuming. I tried contacting apple with no reply as of yet. Hopefully, someone can figure this out.

Comment: What iOS version / hardware?

Comment: Updated the question with information on iOS version and hardware.

Comment: Sorry... I put this as a answer by mistake: Did you see this one from Stack Overflow... this might be your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902061/ios-development-after-updating-my-iphone-4-to-ios-4-3-beta-3-my-app-says-this?rq=1

Comment: @logixologist thanks for the tip, but no wildcards are used in the bundle id. Game Center sandbox seems too unstable to test and develop multiplayer games. The game we're working on is developed in Unity3D, which means simulator testing is not an option. I'm running out of ideas. If you're a Unity developer working on a multiplayer game for iOS, you might want to consider other networking solutions such as Photon Cloud until these GC oddities are resolved.

Comment: have you tried deleting the app from the working device and than put it just on one other device? it could be something with user number limit. or with supported devices that you have set

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360233/this-game-is-not-recognized-by-game-center-iphone-development ?

Answer (score 1):

may be it is related to internet connection, as i got this error on iPod4 at home in the same day that way working at office